# stripping punctuation and finding unique words in Python

Tags: python, if-statement, while-loop, infinite-loop

So my task is as such:

Write a program that displays a list of all the unique words found in the file uniq_words.txt.
Print your results in alphabetic order and lowercase. Hint: Store words as the elements of a set;
remove punctuations by using the string.punctuation from the string module.

Currently, the code that I have is:

```
def main():
    import string

    with open('uniq_words.txt') as content:
        new = sorted(set(content.read().split()))
        for i in new:
            while i in string.punctuation:
                new.discard(i)
                print(new)

main()
```

If I run the code as such, it goes into an infinite loop printing the unique words over and over again. There sre still words in my set that appear as i.e "value." or "never/have". How do I remove the punctuation with the string.punctuation module? Or am I approaching this from a wrong direction? Would appreciate any advice!

Edit: The link does not help me, in that the method given does not work in a list.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Best way to strip punctuation from a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/265960/best-way-to-strip-punctuation-from-a-string)

Comment: @GiftZwergrapper I've actually read through that post previously, but I don't think it solves my question here.

Answer (score 2):

My solution:

```
import string
with open('sample_string.txt') as content:
    sample_string = content.read()
    print(sample_string)
    # Sample string: containing punctuation! As well as CAPITAL LETTERS and duplicates duplicates.
    sample_string = sample_string.strip('\n')
    sample_string = sample_string.translate(str.maketrans('', '', string.punctuation)).lower()
    out = sorted(list(set(sample_string.split(" "))))
    print(out)
    # ['and', 'as', 'capital', 'containing', 'duplicates', 'letters', 'punctuation', 'sample', 'string', 'well']
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comment. Currently I'm getting this error: AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'translate' when I try to run the code.

Comment: That's probably due to the way you read your file. Try this above the line creating the error: `sample_text = ' '.join(sample_text)`, that should convert your list into a string.

Comment: `
def main():
    import string

    with open('uniq_words.txt') as content:
        new1 = content.read().split()
        new2= ' '.join(new1)
        nopunc = new2.translate(str.maketrans('', '', string.punctuation)).lower()
        out = sorted(list(set(nopunc,split(" "))))
       
            
main()
`
is this what you mean?

Answer (score 0):

This is actually *two* tasks, so let's split this into two questions. I will deal with your problem regarding stripping punctuation, because you have shown own efforts in this matter. For the problem of determining unique words, please open a new question (and also look for similar questions here on stack overflow before posting a new question, I am pretty sure you will find something useful!)

You correctly found out that you are ending up in an infinite loop. This is because your `while` loop condition is always true, once `i` is a punctuation character. Removing `i` from `new` does not change that. You avoid this by using a simple `if`-condition. Actually, your code is mixing up the concept of `while` and of `if` and your scenario is tailored for an `if`-statement. I think you thought you needed a `while` loop, because you had the concept of iteration in mind. But you are already iterating over `content` in the for loop. So, the bug fix would be:

```
for i in new:
    if i in string.punctuation:
        new.discard(i)
```

However, a different and more "pythonic" way would be to use list comprehension instead of a `for`-loop

```py
with open("uniq_words.txt") as content:
    stripped_content = "".join([
        x 
        for x in content.read() 
        if x not in string.punctuation
    ])
```

Comment: Your more "pythonic" way doesn't work. This code has invalid syntax..

Comment: @GiftZwergrapper You are right, I was a bit too quick and it was a slip of the pen. I updated it and it works now.